# Optimizing reading very large csv and writing it to SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, bigdata

I have a 10gb csv file of userIDs and genders which are sometimes duplicated.

```
userID,gender
372,f
37261,m
23,m
4725,f
...
```

Here's my code for importing csv and writing it to SQLite database:

```
import sqlite3
import csv


path = 'genders.csv'
user_table = 'Users'

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(f'''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {user_table}''')

cur.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {user_table} (
            userID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
            gender INTEGER,
            PRIMARY KEY (userID))''')

with open(path) as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # skip header        
    next(datareader, None)
    for counter, line in enumerate(datareader):
        # change gender string to integer
        line[1] = 1 if line[1] == 'f' else 0

        cur.execute(f'''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {user_table} (userID, gender) 
                    VALUES ({int(line[0])}, {int(line[1])})''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

For now, it takes 10 seconds to process 1MB file (In reality, I have more columns and also create more tables.). 
I don't think pd.to_sql can be used because I want to have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cursor.execute` for every line, use `cursor.executemany` and insert all data at once.

Store your values in format `_list=[(a,b,c..),(a2,b2,c2...),(a3,b3,c3...)......]`

```
cursor.executemany('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {user_table} (userID, gender,...) 
                    VALUES (?,?,...)''',(_list))
conn.commit()
```

Info:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3

Comment: Wouldn't that list be bigger than my RAM?

Comment: You could break down the list using counter and then do multiple executemany

Comment: Thanks. It still works more than 5 times slower than pd.to_sql.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to give `executemany()` an iterator that reads and converts the data from the CSV on the fly.

Comment: Can you propose a more detailed answer about it? Thank you.